# Within a python package, how can I reference the local variables of the module that is importing it?

Tags: python, import, global, local-variables

**UPDATED WITH SOLUTION AT BOTTOM**

I have created a dsutils package to be imported and used for a number of projects. One aspect of this package is a pdf reader wrapper. It is an object that goes down a hierarchy of different pdf parsing tools (pymupdf, pypdf2, form recognizer, etc) and let's us design projects around the wrapper's universal functionality instead of designing projects around a specific pdf parsing package.

I want to allow for individual projects to override the hierarchy using their own config.py module inside of their project. So that when they import dsutils.pdf.reader, it checks for the hierarchy in the project's local config.py file before using the default hierarchy within dsutils.pdf.reader. I can't figure out how to reference the local variables of the module importing dsutils.pdf.reader within dsutils.pdf.reader itself.

I have tried referencing globals() like this:
project_notebook.ipynb

```
test_variable = 42
'test_variable' in globals()
```

and it returns True.

Within dsutils.pdf.reader.py, I have something like this:

```
Reader:
    ...
    def check_globals(self):
        return globals()
```

And back to project_notebook.ipynb, I get something like this:

```
test_variable = 42
pdf_reader = dsutils.pdf.reader.Reader()
'test_variable' in pdf_reader.check_globals()
```

and I get False.

To expand further, I've also tried something functionally similar to this:
Within dsutils.pdf.reader.py:

```
CONFIG = {
    'pdf_parsing_hierarchy': ['pymupdf', 'pypdf2', 'adobe']
}

Reader:
    def __init__(self, pdf_parsing_hierarchy=CONFIG['pdf_parsing_hierarchy']):
        self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy=pdf_parsing_hierarchy
```

And back to project_notebook.ipynb:

```
import dsutils.pdf.reader
dsutils.pdf.reader.CONFIG['pdf_parsing_hierarchy'] = ['form recognizer']

pdf_reader = Reader()
pdf_reader.pdf_parsing_hierarchy
```

And instead of returning ['form recognizer'] in the local version of dsutils.pdf.reader.CONFIG, it returns the original dsutils.pdf.reader.CONFIG: ['pymupdf', 'pypdf2', 'adobe']

I can pass the overridden hierarchy to Reader during instantiation, but I was hoping for a way to reference the local CONFIG (if available) by default.
Thanks!

**SOLUTION**
Thanks everyone for commenting. While I didn't use any specific answer, you helped point me in the right direction. I realize my questions were more geared towards answering debugging questions than getting the actual answer. The key was using a combination of sys.argv and os.path to check the original module for a corresponding config.py file. Once I could do that, it's just a matter of checking to make sure the necessary variables are there and if not, go with the default variables.
Anyway, here is my actual solution.

In dsutils.pdf.reader.py

```
import os
import sys
import importlib.util

project_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
project_name = project_directory.split('/')[-1]

try:
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("config", f"{project_directory}/config.py")
    config = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules['config'] = config
    spec.loader.exec_module(config)
    if "pdf_parsing_hierarchy" not in config.CONFIG:
        print(f"The config.py file in {project_name} does not contain the necessary 'pdf_parsing_hierarchy' key.\nUsing default hierarchy if not explicitly referenced.")
        from dsutils.pdf.config import CONFIG
    else:
        print(f"The default pdf parsing hierarchy has been overridden for {project_name}")
        CONFIG = config.CONFIG
except:
    print(f'No config.py detected in {project_name}.\nUsing the default pdf parsing hierarchy if not explicitly referenced.')
    from dsutils.pdf.config import CONFIG
```

Comment: Every module has its *own* global scope (so the name itself is somewhat of a misnomer). For `pdf_reader.check_globals()` to return a dict containing `test_variable`, you would need to make an assignment like `disutils.pdf.reader.test_variable = 42`, defining the variable in the correct global namespace.

Comment: `globals` Return the dictionary containing the current scope's global variables.

Answer (score 0):

The `Reader` class isn't being passed the relevant `CONFIG` value. It's reading the mutable value stored as a default argument to its `__init__` method, whose reference is being overwritten within the notebook. This causes the class to initialize with the cached value it has stored in the method definition. It's [highly](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-pitfall-mutable-default-arguments-9385e8265422) [discouraged](https://hackernoon.com/the-surprising-case-of-mutable-default-arguments) to use mutable types as default arguments to methods. You could try passing in the relevant configurations, or have the `__init__` method pull from the global mutable data structure directly.

Overwriting the reference in the global during runtime to satisfy one use-case is also, generally, not what is intended by having a default configuration (which is capitalized, signalling to the reader that it will remain constant).

dsutils.pdf.reader.py:

```
CONFIG = {
    'pdf_parsing_hierarchy': ['pymupdf', 'pypdf2', 'adobe']
}

class Reader:
    def __init__(self, pdf_parsing_hierarchy=None):
        if pdf_parsing_hierarchy != None:
            self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy = pdf_parsing_hierarchy
        else:
            self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy = CONFIG["pdf_parsing_hierarchy"]
```

project_notebook.ipynb:

```
import dsutils.pdf.reader

# the first way:
pdf_reader = Reader(['form recognizer'])
pdf_reader.pdf_parsing_hierarchy  
['form recognizer']

pdf_reader = Reader()
pdf_reader.pdf_parsing_hierarchy  
['pymupdf', 'pypdf2', 'adobe']                                                                                                                     


# the second way overwrites the reference in the global permanently:
dsutils.pdf.reader.CONFIG['pdf_parsing_hierarchy'] = ['form recognizer']

pdf_reader = Reader()
pdf_reader.pdf_parsing_hierarchy                                                                                                                       
['form recognizer']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)
Return the dictionary implementing the current module namespace. For code within functions, this is set when the function is defined and remains the same regardless of where the function is called.

You must define as `test_variable = 42` in "reader.py"

And in the code below;

```
CONFIG = {
    'pdf_parsing_hierarchy': ['pymupdf', 'pypdf2', 'adobe']
}

Reader:
    def __init__(self, pdf_parsing_hierarchy=CONFIG['pdf_parsing_hierarchy']):
        self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy=pdf_parsing_hierarchy
```

`pdf_parsing_hierarchy`'s value is evaluated before `__init__` is defined. i.e. the name `__init__` is assigned an object of type function but before assignment the function's default parameters' values are evaluated to concrete values. When the values are evaluated they are looked up in the current scope, enclosing scope, global scope and the builtins of the module where the function is defined.

By the time you change the value of `CONFIG['pdf_parsing_hierarchy']` the default value of the function parameter had already been evaluated and assigned.

You have to pass another value to override the default value.

Btw, you should not pass a mutable object as a default value to a parameter.
Best practice is;

```
def __init__(self, pdf_parsing_hierarchy=None):
  if pdf_parsing_hierarchy is None:
    self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy=CONFIG['pdf_parsing_hierarchy']
  else:
    self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy=pdf_parsing_hierarchy
```

Here `self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy` is now defined at runtime, not at definition of `__init__`. So if you change `CONFIG['pdf_parsing_hierarchy']` before instantiating `Reader` it'll be reflected in `self.pdf_parsing_hierarchy`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it is not advised to use global() to get global scope variables. But you need something to handle `globalization` as I call it.
The way I do this, is to create a class named `Config` which stores whatever I want to be stored inside the class scope and have `classmethods` as its functions (if needed).

I store my configurations inside a json file in the project directory and then use one of the `Config` `classmethods` to read those configurations from the mentioned json file.

Here is an example of what I do in config.py

```python
class Config:
    config = None
    @classmethod
    def configure(cls):
        with open(file="config.json", mode="r") as config_file:
            Config.config = json.load(fp=config_file)
```

inside my main entry point `main.py` first I call configure and because it is a class, everywhere I import it the configurations are set in the Config class. Here is the way I do that in the `main.py`

```python
from config import Config
from dsutils.pdf.reader import Reader()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config.Configure()
    pdf_reader = Reader()
    pdf_reader.pdf_parsing_hierarchy
```

Please take into account that the `Config` class should be also imported wherever you need configurations to be used. For example inside the `reader` module in the `dsutils`, you need to import the `Config` class and use it's settings wherever necessary. Here is how you can do that:

```python
from config import Config

## Use Config class within functions, or inside the reader module itself.
```

This way the configurations are set before anything else and then the `Config` class acts as a global variable to move around things you want.